# Could I say "I'm looking at the project"?

Tags: word-choice

Someone is examining an Internet project at Codeplex.com.
Can he say "I'm looking at the project 'Project name'", or it is a mistake? What is the best way to say it?

Comment: Hi omlin and welcome to the site. Please try to be as specific as possible in the wording of your questions, as general proofreading requests are [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). What is causing the confusion for you — the verb, the article, the preposition, something else? Thanks and welcome again.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll try to be more specific next time. Here I meant the verb + the preposition combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "looking at the project" and "looking into the project" are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Beckett's answer is correct. In order to streamline the sentence, I might get rid of *the* and say something like "I'm looking at project 'Name'."

Comment: Or, streamlined further, "I'm looking at projectname", assuming that "projectname" is unambiguous.